# How to use Tensorboard within a notebook running on Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, tensorboard

I have a Jupyter notebook running within an `Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab` (https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/) environment, and I want to use Tensordboard to monitor my model's performance inside the notebook.

I have used the following commands to set up the Tensorboard:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
# tb_log_dir variable holds the path to the log directory
%tensorboard --logdir tb_log_dir
```

But nothing shows up in the output of the cell where I execute the commands. See:

[image]

The two buttons shown in the picture are not responding, BTW.

How to solve this problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the canonical way to use tensorboard in AWS Sagemaker, it should be supported also by Studio Lab, it is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-tensorboard.html). Basically install tensorboard and using the `EFS_PATH_LOG_DIR` launch tensorboard using the embedded console (you can do the following also from a cell):

```
pip install tensorboard
tensorboard --logdir <EFS_PATH_LOG_DIR>
```

Be careful with the EFS_PATH_LOG_DIR, be sure this folder is valida path from the location you are, for example by default you are located in `studio-lab-user/sagemaker-studiolab-notebooks/` so the proper command would be `!tensorboard --logdir logs/fit`.

Then open a browser to:

```
https://<YOUR URL>/studiolab/default/jupyter/proxy/6006/
```

Comment: I tried the method described in the link that you shared. But I could not open the Tensorboard dashboard via the subdomain path mentioned there. (I mean the URL at the end of your post.) I think accessing the Tensorboard dashboard on ``Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab`` could be different from ``Amazon SageMaker Studio``, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should work the same, your URL should be something like this:

https://<YOUR_URL>.studio.<YOUR_REGION>.sagemaker.aws/studiolab/default/jupyter/proxy/6006

Comment: I ran the example notebook from https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started in `Amazon SageMaker Studio Lab` witout any error, but when I open `https://<YOUR_URL>.studio.<YOUR_REGION>.sagemaker.aws/studiolab/default/jupyter/proxy/6006` (with proper URL and region information), I only see an empty (HTML) page.

Comment: I edited my question, I just tried and works.. it tooks days for AWS to activate a studio lab account for me, but it works! The URL is a little bit different from my previous reply.

Comment: glad it helped, can you please mark you question as solved accepting my answer? thanks